# Eclipse Paho Javascript Client and browser support

Tags: javascript, apache, browser, mqtt

One of my RPi's is configured as webserver (Apache2). On the same RPi runs a MQTT broker (Mosquitto). The website is configured as follows:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available# cat 000-default.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

#--- PAUL ---

ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location /mqtt>
  ProxyPass "ws://127.0.0.1:9001"
  ProxyPassReverse "ws://127.0.0.1:9001"
</Location>

#--- PAUL ---
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
root@raspberrypi:/etc/apache2/sites-available#
```

And mosquitto is configured as follows:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto# cat mosquitto.conf
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883

listener 9001
protocol websockets
root@raspberrypi:/etc/mosquitto#
```

I've written a very basic webpage to test the functionality (right on the screenshot). Things work fine in MS Edge( bottom left), but fails in some other browsers (Firefox, top left) :

[image: Screenshot]

I'm not sure this is a RPi problem or a browser problem, but I need to solve this.

Anyone an idea what could cause this error and how I could solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Please edit the question to include the text from the images as they are unreadable (and unsearchable) at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Ok, index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>IoThings & Trains</title>
        <script src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/paho-mqtt.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/IoTT_Web.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
        <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
        <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World !!
    </body>
</html>
```

IoTT_Web.js :

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(location.hostname, Number(location.port), "IoTT_Web");

client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});

function onConnect()
{
    console.log("onConnect");
    client.subscribe("#");
}

function onConnectionLost(responseObject)
{
    if(responseObject.errorCode !== 0)
    {
        console.log("onConnectionLost: "+responseObject.errorMessage);
    }
}

function onMessageArrived(message)
{
    console.log("onMessageArrived:\n\tFrom " + message.destinationName + "\n\tPayload " + message.payloadString);
}
```

Error messages from Firefox console:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
paho-mqtt.js:1046
LibraryFactory/PahoMQTT</ClientImpl.prototype._doConnect
http://192.168.1.100/scripts/paho-mqtt.js:1046:18
LibraryFactory/PahoMQTT</ClientImpl.prototype.connect
http://192.168.1.100/scripts/paho-mqtt.js:881:4
Client/this.connect
http://192.168.1.100/scripts/paho-mqtt.js:2004:4
<anonymous>
http://192.168.1.100/scripts/IoTT_Web.js:6:1
```

And finaly, the (correct) output from Edge (console) :

```
 HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
192.168.1.100 (1,1)

 onConnect

 onMessageArrived:
    From TBTIoT/Devices/11936008677624121892/Status
    Payload Online

 onMessageArrived:
    From IoTT/Devices/11936008677624121892/Status
    Payload Online
```